# Initial permeability of toroids in ATX power supply?

Tags: rf, transformer

I'm interested in re-using output side or possibly the line filter toroids from a junk ATX switching supply. All turns are removed, just the core.

I think these are powdered iron cores and any guess what the initial permeability may be for these cores?  My application is in the low end of HF region (1 to 7 MHz) to be used as transmission line transformer cores.

Comment: Photos would help, as would any specific info about the donor power supply.

Comment: 7Mhz isn't such low freq, OK you might be in region of hundreds Mhz, but a SMPS is in region of few kHz.

Comment: Powdered iron is very lossy in the MHz region, you will have to keep your flux density very low.  Ferrite would be a better choice.

Comment: Could you please re-word your question and make it more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to measure it. Wind ten turns of wire on the core and measure the inductance.

There are many ways of measuring the inductance, depending on what test equipment you have available. In a pinch, you can even use sound ports of a desktop or laptop computer. However, you may need to add more turns to the core to get the inductance high enough to work within the frequency range available from the computer.